# Ruby 1.9.2 Find.find encoding

Tags: windows, encoding, utf-8, find, ruby-1.9.2

I know that you can do `Dir.entries('.', {:encoding => 'utf-8'})` and it works properly, but I can't find any way to force the encoding when doing `Find.find`. On Windows, the first method correctly reads a filename of 舦舨.txt, and doing `File.file?` on the value returns `true`. However, doing `Find.find` returns ??.txt, even though ruby says its encoding is utf-8. Also, `File.file?` returns `false`.

Is there no way to set the encoding on `Find.find`?

Comment: FYI, seems to work on linux: Find.find("舦舨.txt") { |f| puts File.file? f } => true

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Find.find(dir)
```

I found

```
Find.find(dir.encode('utf-8'))
```

works